# Trying to make my Cypher Statement case insensitive

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I got a cypher query that is working on a neo4j repository and I would like to make this query case insensitive.

Tried with `=~` but this is not working.

```
@Query (countQuery = "match (n:Patient) where n.born = {0} OR n.lastName = {0} OR n.email = {0} return n") Page<Patient> findByLastNameOrBornOrEmail(String lastName, String born, String email, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=~` alone won't work, you need to prefix the string with `(?i)` like so:

```
WHERE n.lastname =~ '(?i)' + {0}
```

Be aware that indexes cannot be used when performing lookups like this, the planner would need to do a label scan of all :Patient nodes, which will get less performant as :Patient nodes increase.

If you're using Neo4j 3.5.x, you might want to consider usage of [fulltext schema indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/index/#schema-index-fulltext-search) which can cover several properties of a node, (rather than just a single property) which would be perfect for your case, and is case insensitive. You may need to figure out where to do the score cutoff though, to only get relevant results.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, it works like this.

I am using pagination in my app and i give the opportunity to the user to choose betweern 1 to 20 entries per page. Do you still think that this solution will make my app less perfomant?
The question is, will pagination load all entries and render them after the request or only the entries that the user has choosen?

Comment: For pagination you typically need ordering, and I don't see an ORDER BY in the query. The query will have to find the results, do the SKIP over whatever you're defining here, then apply the LIMIT to the results returned. Note that when returning nodes or relationships, properties for those nodes are not accessed (so they can be returned to the caller) unless they are actually being returned, so nodes that are being skipped because of SKIP, or are outside the limited returned set, won't have their properties accessed.